# How to select default Shipping method

Tags: cart, shipping, shipping-methods, onepage-checkout

I have various shipping methods configured and would like to select a default one based on country of the visitor or something.

For example if the user is from Spain (Or spanish Locale) then default shipping is ... and if from another country then International shipping.

Can anybody help me out here? I don't have a clue where to start.

Also I want it to be applied by default, because we have an PayPal express checkout and if I click on it without entering the cart and selecting the Shipping method from the Estimate section, the shipping cost's are not applied when Paying by PayPal... This is a problem..

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your custom shipping method.

To do so, create a custom class extended from `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract`, and start writing your business logic code inside overloaded `collectRates` method.

```
class Arturas_CountryBasedShipping_Model_Shipping_Carrier_ShippingMethod extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract {

    protected $_code = 'countrybasedshipping';

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
        // skip if not enabled
        if( !Mage::getStoreConfig( 'carriers/' . $this->_code . '/active' ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        // Fetching a country based price
        $cb_price = $this->getCountryShippingPrice( $request->getDestCountryId() );

        $result   = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        $method   = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle('Contry Based Shipping');
        $method->setCost($cb_price);
        $method->setPrice($cb_price);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

You also may want to read [this article](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/).

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. 

Is it posible to assign auto shipping method from the one that I have in the configuration? The problem is that we have other modules (provided by the shipping company) and I would like to assign one of those as default. 

I tryed using this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-shipping-pro.html but it doesn't work.. I don't know why, no errors nothing..

Comment: Sure. Use setMethod method with code of your preferred shipping method.

Comment: Could you please mark it as accepted (if it's been accepted of course)